# What control for date picking is good for MVC2?

Tags: user-interface, datetime, asp.net-mvc-2, controls

What control can I use to select dates for ASP.Net MVC2?

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally a big fan of [this one](http://blog.w3visions.com/2009/04/date-time-picker-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/) because it's for date and time.  If you just need date it can probably be adjusted accordingly, but for any fields that require date and time it would maintain a consistent UI across the site (rather than one picker for dates and another for times).